# How to connect to SQL Server 2012 via PHP 5.5.7 Red Hat

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect MS SQL Server 2012 with php. My OS is Linux Red Hat and I am using PHP 5.5.7 version. This is my connection function:

```
    function connect_ms_sql()
{
    try {
        $hostname = "xxx";
        $port = 111;
        $dbname = "xxx";
        $username = "xxx";
        $pw = "xxx";
        $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname", "$username", "$pw");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        exit;
    }
    unset($dbh);
}
```

When I run this function, it shows me error: `Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver`. How I can fix it? I tried with FreeTDS, same error. Please help me!

Comment: Did you try to use [microsoft's ODBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160)?

Comment: Thank you Dmitry Polyakov! I had installed this driver, but when I run `odbc_connect`, it shows me error: `Call to undefined function odbc_connect()`

Comment: Configure ODBC source according to this [article](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-odbc.php#107128) and continue using `PDO` as you do in example above.